# Cannot print a function's return value in another function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, function-call

I have a function named Login() that reads a username(ex. `"John"`) and then create a password that is the username itself with each letter upper or lower in random (ex. `"JoHn"`)inside a new function called `password()` .However when I try to print the password in Login() as a return statement from `password()` it prints null;

This is the function that returns the password :

```
void Login()  
{  
    char passwd[20];
    char name[20];

    printf(" Please enter your username : \n");
    do
    {
        scanf(" %s",&name);
    }while(strcmp(name,"John")!=0);



    printf("Your password is : %s\n",password(name));

    printf("Please enter your password : \n");

    do
    {
        scanf(" %s",&passwd);
    }while(strcmp(passwd,password(name))!=0);

}
```

And this is the function that returns the password :

```
char password( char pass[])
{

    int i;
    int k;

    for(i=0;i<strlen(pass);i++)
    {
        k= rand()%2;
        if(k==1)
        {
            pass[i]=toupper(pass[i]);
        }
        else{
            pass[i]=tolower(pass[i]);
        }   
    }

    return pass;
}
```

Now when I run `Login()` in `main` i get

> "Your password is : (null)"

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Also turn on compiler warnings - the compiler will point out a number of serious problems in your code.

Comment: Your compiler should be giving you a few warnings about the code you show. If you don't get warnings then enable more warnings and treat them as errors. Hint about your problem: What is the return type of `password`? What are you trying to return? How are you using the returned value?

Comment: i want to return the modified  username from Login() as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue: Your `password()` function actually return a `char`, whereas it is supposed to return a pointer to the first element of a `char` array (modified one).

That said, there are other issues.

- You call `password(name)` multiple times (in `do...while` loop), whereas, your input is supposed to be validated against the result of the first call. As in every call, the returned string is randomized, successive calls will return different results. You need to store the result of the first call and compare the input against it.
- `scanf(" %s",&name);` should be `scanf("%19s",name);`, because

  - The `19` will length-limit the input, avoiding possible buffer overflows.
  - The array type, in most cases, automatically decays to a type as pointer to the first element - use of `&` is not needed.

  Same for password input also.

---

EDIT:

Here is a working version of the code: [Live version](https://repl.it/repls/YellowishSuperbTransversals)

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char* password( char pass[])
{

    int i;
    int k;

    for(i=0;i<strlen(pass);i++)
    {
        k= rand()%2;
        if(k==1)
        {
            pass[i]=toupper(pass[i]);
        }
        else{
            pass[i]=tolower(pass[i]);
        }   
    }

    return pass;
}

int main(void)
{
    char passwd[20];
    char name[20];

    printf(" Please enter your username : \n");
    do
    {
        scanf("%19s",name);
    }while(strcmp(name,"John")!=0);


    char * res = password(name);
    printf("Your password is : %s\n",res);

    do
    {
        printf("Please enter your password : \n");
        scanf("%19s",passwd);
    }while(strcmp(passwd,res)!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: now my program terminates after i write the username

Comment: What do you mean terminate?

Comment: it means that my program ends

Comment: I found it earlier .Thank you anyway